# select between years case when statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I wrote a query

```
 WITH sample AS (
  SELECT CAST('2010-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, i.vrp_notificationdate) as deneme
    FROM Incident i
   WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, i.vrp_notificationdate) <= CAST('2011-11-01' AS DATETIME))
SELECT count(DATENAME(mm,l.vrp_notificationdate) +' '+DATENAME(yy,l.vrp_notificationdate)) as Toplam,DATENAME(mm,l.vrp_notificationdate) +' '+DATENAME(yy,l.vrp_notificationdate)
  FROM Incident as l
  group by  
  DATENAME(mm,l.vrp_notificationdate) +' '+DATENAME(yy,l.vrp_notificationdate)
```

the query show

> ```
> 10    November 2011
> 101   October 2011
> 4 September 2011
> ```

but i want to show this .

> ```
>  0 january 2010
>  0 february 2010
>  -
>  -
>  -
>  10 November 2011
>  101 October 2011
>  4 september 2011
>  0 december  2011
>  0 february  2011
> ```

i tried case when statement,but query show same result
How to solve what i use

Best regards.

Comment: What does the raw data look like? What is the intended logic? And please try to make your code readable

Comment: @gbn i edit my query,i have column name of notificationdate on Incident table.notificationdate type of date.i select count between twwo years all count if months value doesnt exist i want to show 0.

Comment: @engcmreng, try amending the part of your main query that says `FROM Incident as l` to say `FROM sample as l` and let us know what the results are. (At the moment, you have declared a CTE before your main query, but you are not using the CTE in the query.)

Comment: @aF thanks your advice,i agree with u,but i older ueation is not closed as i want :)

Comment: @aF actually only explanation,my english not good,sometimes i wrote wrong what i wanted so some my question is not closed :).again thanks your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to show data that doesn't exist. The idea of this solution is to

- Add dummy dates
- Assign a count of 0 to each dummy date
- Union your original results with this dummy dates
- Group into a final result

#### SQL Statement

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '01-01-2010'
;WITH Dates(d) AS (
  SELECT @StartDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATEADD(mm, 1, d) AS Date
  FROM    Dates
  WHERE   d < '12-01-2012'
)       
,WITH sample AS (
  SELECT  CAST('2010-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATEADD(dd, 1, i.vrp_notificationdate) as deneme
  FROM    Incident i
  WHERE   DATEADD(dd, 1, i.vrp_notificationdate) <= CAST('2011-11-01' AS DATETIME)
)
SELECT  SUM(Toplam) AS Toplam
        , DateFormat
FROM    (
          SELECT  COUNT(DATENAME(mm,l.vrp_notificationdate) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy,l.vrp_notificationdate)) AS Toplam
                  , DATENAME(mm,l.vrp_notificationdate) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy,l.vrp_notificationdate) AS DateFormat
                  , CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), l.vrp_notificationdate, 112) as orderDate
          FROM    Incident as l
          GROUP BY
                  DATENAME(mm,l.vrp_notificationdate) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy,l.vrp_notificationdate)
                  , CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), l.vrp_notificationdate, 112)
          UNION ALL       
          SELECT  0 AS Toplam
                  , DATENAME(mm, d) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy, d)
                  , CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), d.d, 112) as orderDate
          FROM    Dates d
        ) g
GROUP BY
        DateFormat                  
ORDER BY
        g.orderDate
```

Comment: @engcmreng - Any luck with the solution?

Comment: i used editing to my query.Thanks but also i have a question,i want to order that dates and i add order by datepart(mm,DateFormat)+''+datepart(yy,DateFormat) but it isnt sort correctly,how i sort correctly by ascending.Thanks.

Comment: @engcmreng - I have added a sort order.

Comment: thanks for sharing,but i take this error:vrp_notificationdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.And i edit query again and this time sorting correct when count 0 by months,else order by date.How to solve.Sorry if i stole your time.

Comment: @engcmreng - I didn't take into account the grouping. The query has changed, could you verify the results?

Comment: thanks your answers.this query run correctly.thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the date doesn't appear, it means that there isn't any value present for that date. So, it's impossible to get that date to appear in the result.

To pass this the simplest solution is to:

1. Create a table with all the possible dates and another column that will start with zero.
2. Update that table with the results of the query that you made (update the column that start with zero to have the count values).
3. Display the end results from the new table:

> ```
> select countValues + ' ' + dateValues from newTable
> ```

If you have any doubt, just ask :)

Comment: yes,i know date doesnt appear,there isnt any value,so i want to show this column marked as count 0,i thought create a table but i think maybe it s a simple way,like function.Thanks again.

Comment: you can use one of the other answers or implement the solution that I gave above. new table -> update it -> return results

Answer (score 0):

Why do you provide "WITH sample AS" when you do not use sample?

I'ld use this recursive query to build all dates for your result table.

```
WITH sample (d) AS ( 
    SELECT CAST('2010-01-01' AS DATETIME)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(mm, 1, d) FROM sample WHERE DATEADD(mm, 1, d) <= CAST('2011-11-01' AS DATETIME)
)
select * from sample
```

You could then outer join this table with your Incident table to get the count of incidents for each month.

If you want to see a lot of months or even days, you might get an MSG 530 because of too much recursion. In this case you need the add OPTION (MAXRECURSION ) after "select * from sample".

Comment: why i dont use my query was very confused,i tried a lot of different way,i think wrote wrong query here,actually i wrote that specify i wanted.